# PL SQL Stored Procedure for new Transaction and order

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, insert

I'm giving a small snippet of my code but I 'm receiving the below error when trying to create a new order for a stored Oracle pl sql procedure.
line 83 is the insert statement in the code and line 84 is in the insert part of the statement.

83/5   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
84/47  PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

```
 BEGIN
--Initializing values for variables
x_rowcount := 0;
x_stockonhand := 0;
Totaldue := 0;

 --Total due calculation
--(price of phone*quantity + shipping cost)*1.06 (assuming 6% sales tax)
Totaldue := (((i_price * c_p_qty) + i_shipping_cost) * 1.06);

SAVEPOINT start_transaction;  -- mark a savepoint
 --INSERT  a new record into order table. 
INSERT INTO orders(o_id,c_id,p_id,s_id,order_date,o_qty,order_total,card_type,cc_number,exp_date,shipping_status) 
VALUES (orders_seq.nextval, c_c_id,c_p_id,s_id,sysdate,c_p_qty,Totaldue,c_card_type,c_cc_number,c_exp_date,'Not shipped yet');
```

Comment: think you might have to get your sequence first prior to the insert. so maybe something like right before the insert select orders_seq.nextval into myOrdersSeq from dual;   (of course you need to define myOrdersSeq)

Answer (score 0):

Check your declaration section. Usually this error appears when you make a typo in variable name or variable not declared. For example:

```
SQL> create table tmp (id number, str varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> declare
 a number;
begin
  insert into tmp (id, str)
  values (a, a1);
end;
/  
  values (a, a1);
             *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because one or more of the values in your `VALUES(...,...)` section is invalid.

I would suggest checking each one to see that they are valid.  For example, is `c_c_id` declared and given a value somewhere else in the code?  If not, this is likely your problem.  Each one needs to be declared and given a value before it can be put in the `VALUES(...,...)` section of the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO orders(o_id,c_id,p_id,s_id,order_date,o_qty,order_total,card_type,cc_number,exp_date,shipping_status) 
VALUES (orders_seq.nextval, c_c_id,c_p_id,s_id,sysdate,c_p_qty,Totaldue,c_card_type,c_cc_number,c_exp_date,'Not shipped yet');
```